# Function tracing per thread

Tags: function, buffer, trace, tracing

I have a complex multi threaded application running on a Cent OS 5.8
the application is coded using C and C++

I am searching for a **FUNCTION TRACING** tool which can help me do the following.

1. Trace all external and internal function information(function name, Input out parameters) per thread into a buffer
2. provide configuration to save the buffers on **REQUEST** to the disk.
3. Provide configuration to **Enable/disable** tracing per Process.
4. Provide configuration to **Enable/disable** internal function per Process/thread.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure such tool exists, but I can think of two possible ways of doing it in a relatively painless way:

- write a GDB script ([thread specific breakpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Thread_002dSpecific-Breakpoints.html), [logging instead of breaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206447/gdb-logging-something-instead-of-breaking), etc.)
- write an `LD_PRELOAD library` overriding the functions you want to trace (example with `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` override [here](http://bobah.net/d4d/tools/cpp-heapmap)) and use [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/) to display the calling stack